# Single Board Computer with no hardware memory for firmware

Tags: firmware, sbc

Im looking for a SBC that has

- Completely no hardware memory for the firmware (e.g BIOS,  ,etc.), i think raspberry pi has that, except the bootloader which is ROM

OR

- All firmware memory on the board is ROM and or EPROM, no EEPROM

Raspberry pi is a perfect example, but i need a bigger range of selection, so im looking for some keywords here. Or are there even any keywords for this or is that thing that you always have to look at specs, components etc.?

My question is are there already given knowing names for these devices that correspond to this?

Very beginner form

There are microcontrollers on the board, microcontroller stored
firmware (software), there are what i know ROM, EPROM, EEPROM. The
EEPROM you can theoretically reflash/hack via a digital
attack/physically attack, i only care about digital attacks. ROM, EPROM you only can hack when you have it physically.

- ROM, EPROM = Safe from digital attacks.
- EEPROM = Not safe from digital attacks.

No memory footprint SBC, ...?

Comment: This question needs some improvement please describe the problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: What is hardware vs firmware memory ?

Comment: I mean the firmware (software) like the BIOS which is most of the time stored on hardware EEPROM. Question answered?

Comment: Your question boils down to: I'm looking for a board with bootloader flash write enable being controlled by a physical jumper.

Answer (score 1):

Almost every microprocessor (ARM, PIC, ect) on the market has some kind of ROM (usually flash) that is built in to the microprocessor. I am unaware of any SBC's  that don't have ROM.

A processor needs a memory location to tell it where to boot from. A processor can boot from many places, such as RAM, ROM, flash (like an SD card), or even load up programs from USB, serial, or ethernet.

Once the processor loads the memory location a program can be run to copy the rest of the program from ROM, USB, ect to the RAM. Once the program is in RAM it can be executed.

Because of this if you want to make a device's memory less 'hackable' use a read only memory technology that can only be written to once, like a Programmable Read Only Memory (or PROM) that is [One Time Programmable](https://www.digikey.com/products/en/integrated-circuits-ics/memory-configuration-proms-for-fpgas/697?k=PROM&k=&pkeyword=PROM&pv150=9&FV=ffe002b9&quantity=0&ColumnSort=0&page=1&pageSize=25) (which are being obsoleted fast). This means that no one could hack into your device electronically and change the ROM (but they could still change the RAM, so the exploit would go away when the device was rebooted) The disadvantage is that to change your code you would also not be able to fix any bugs (or security holes) in your program without changing the ROM chip.

A better thing to do would be to use micro controller with an [encrypted rom to prevent tampering](https://www.electronicdesign.com/boards/secure-microcontroller) as someone would have to have the key to read the ROM's true contents.

Comment: The question isn't about avoiding true ROM.  It is seeks a device with no persistent memory which is *writeable* without physical intervention.

Comment: The answer has been edited